# Create a new VSCode extension for different tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to create a **custom VS Code task** with **my own schema** 
docs
[vscode task](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/task-provider)

e.g. A new tree view which is empty and when user click on `+` button (a new tree view with button which is similar source code tree like, add file, add folder, etc but just with `+` button which create a new tasks from two options) he got **list of tasks** when he click on specific task it 
create a `tasks.json` (if it doesn't exist) file  with schema which is related to the task he choose from the list like **tasks1** and if he choose `task2` he get different entry in the `tasks.json` that he need to edit.

The **trick** here, that each task should add different entry in the `tasks.json` file which is generated to the user

e.g.

if user choose **task1** he need to fill (a new entry in the `task.json`)

```
username
password
```

And if he choose **task2**

```
system
endpoint
```

Is it possible to do it in VS Code? Any example with for this can will be helpful.

I've tried the following even it doesn't fit the same scenario I need exactly (different tasks entry in the `tasks.json` file) however it **doesn't** add any task on the `task.json`. More here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/task-provider-sample

Comment: Please stop making trivial edits to this post in an attempt to "bump" it. If you are *substantively improving* the post, or *adding new information*, then that is a fine reason to edit. But several of your last edits were just adding filler or nonsense that doesn't belong in the first place.

Comment: @CodyGray - you edited also :) , I didnt know that "bump" functionality :) thanks for notice.

Comment: This question is too broad, basically you're asking for a code session that walk you through vscode API and teach you how to create an entire extension for your use case. This simply is too much to ask on stackoverflow. Show people what you've done so far, where you got stuck, ask about more specific problem.

Comment: @hackape - I basically took https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/task-provider-sample and try to adopt it without success, what I need is basically a way to add my new entry to the `tasks.json` file, I didnt manage to do it with the `taskprovider` API  but as I need to vscode extension maybe I miss something

Comment: @hackape - if someone can take this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/task-provider-sample , and add just what I need , define two different tasks this is sufficient, as this is a bit tricky I provided a bounty, hope you could help...thanks!

Comment: I completely, agree with @hackape and unfortunately as of your last comment you also agree with him, stackoverflow isn't a place for asking someone to *just add a couple of tasks* and be provided with a bounty as a *payment*